# Rspec.Undefined method `valid?' for :user:Symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I try to create test for users-factories.But when I running test, 'rspec' show me an error

```
Failure/Error: expect(:user).to be_valid
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `valid?' for :user:Symbol
```

this is my user_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe do
  it "has a valid factory" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    expect(:user).to be_valid
  end
end
```

and this is users-factories(with 'faker' gem)

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user do
    email Faker::Internet.email
    password Faker::Internet.password(8)
  end

end
```

how fix and why this method don't work?

sorry for my bad English

Comment: The create user is an object, not the symbol representing that object to Factory Girl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a fix :

```
RSpec.describe do
  it "has a valid factory" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    expect(user).to be_valid
  end
end
```

You passed the symbol `:user` as an argument to the `expect(:user)`, which you shouldn't. You should pass the local variable `user`, you have created, and passed to it `expect(user)`.

Comment: did not recognize you in the hat :)

Comment: @Зелёный he he :) Yes, I wear it.. How is it ?